# HTML form values and 'Back' button

Tags: html, browser

How can one retain HTML form info when hitting the back button? Is this a default HTML or Browser behavior? Or is it Browser dependent?

Answer (score 2):

It is default browser behavior, but ONLY if the page containing the form is cache-able, e.g. has headers set such that the browser is allowed to cache it.

[How does SO's form remember previous input values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2749905/how-does-sos-form-remember)

Answer (score -2):

That i s not a browser behavior, it depends on the technology/framework you use

Comment: This is incorrect. Go here: http://www.formnut.com/examples.php, enter "Bob" into the "your name" field, press submit, press back, see "bob" still in the form, hit view-source to confirm "bob" is not in the source.

Comment: @AlexBlack : I agree with you. This is NOT a framework feature. But rather a browser feature. Actually, if your framework tries to add value, they seem to be overriden by the browser's cached values! which sucks in some cases.